# jQuery fadeOut method is not fading out element

Tags: jquery

I am facing a peculiar problem while I am using jQuery fadeOut method.

When I use below code it is fading out.

`$('#id').fadeOut("slow" );`

But when I use below code it is not fading out, it is just disappear from screen.

`$('#id').fadeOut("slow" ).remove();`

Could anyone say what is the problem ??

Is there any way to make fading out the second one??

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that fadeOut is an animation method, which means it will happen over time, but you are then immediately invoking remove. Instead you can use the callback signature of fadeOut:

```
$('#id').fadeOut('slow', function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Why not `$(this)` for the function?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `callBack function`, Normally `CallBacks` will be fired once after the execution of `parental` tasks.

```
$('#id').fadeOut("slow",function(){ $(this).remove() } );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut) to complete before removing it from the dom using the complete callback.

```
$('#id').fadeOut("slow", function(){
   $(this).remove()
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

its because of the `.remove()` method that runs concurrently with the animation which makes `#id` not yet completely faded out when `remove()` is executed.

You need to put the `remove()` on the fade-out callback

```
$('#id').fadeOut( function() { //the fadeout is finished call the callback function
   $(this).remove();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you don't need to use the `remove()` function as `fadeOut` also removes the element when it is finished fading.